# Splitting strings at multiple delimiters in python

Tags: python, string

I have a file text.txt which contains the ff:

```
apple boy 'cat'
dog, egg fin
goat hat ice!
```

I need to split the text file using spaces and special characters and while also ignoring new lines so that the output will be an array like this:

```
["apple", "boy", "'", "cat", "'", "dog", "egg", "fin", "goat", "hat", "ice", "!"]
```

but so far the output of my code results to something like this:
it returns the string per character and even retains the spaces...

```
["a", "p", "p", "l", "e", "b", "o", "y", "'", "c", "a", "t", "'", "\n," "d", "o", "g", "e", "g", "g", "f", "i", "n", "\n", "g", "o", "a", "t", "h", "a", "t", "i", "c", "e", "!", "\n" ]
```

Here is my code:

```
file=open(text.txt)

for i in file:
        i.split(" ")
        b+=i


print b
```

what to do if importing of any modules is not allowed? especially the re module?

Comment: "not allowed"? Is this homework?

Comment: General idea to solve this: Run two loops. In the first loop, split by " ", In the second loop, for each string in the list, split by ","

Comment: what are the *special* characters? Do you mean punctuation?

Comment: yes, just like the "!" while still retaining it in the array

Comment: `i.split(" ")` doesn't do what you think it does (i.e., mutate the string in place).

Comment: @melpomene And so what if it is his homework? He's still trying to learn, he's tried to solve the problem on his own, and the question is completely valid even if it is homework. Not wanting to import any other modules could be due to many reasons, one of which includes attempt to learn new stuff. Maybe he's learning how for loops and string splitting works, and regex is not a part of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a temp string, find the non-alphanumeric characters wrapping them in spaces both side then split at the end

```
lines ="""apple boy 'cat'
dog, egg fin
goat hat ice!"""

out = []
for line in lines.splitlines():
    temp = ""
    for ch in line:
        if ch.isalnum():
            temp+= ch
        else:
            temp += " {} ".format(ch)
    out.extend(temp.split())
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'boy', "'", 'cat', "'", 'dog', ',', 'egg', 'fin', 'goat', 'hat', 'ice', '!']
```

Using your file is just a matter of iterating over the file object and applying the same logic:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    out = []
    for line in f:
        temp = ""
        for ch in line:
            if ch.isalnum():
                temp += ch
            else:
                temp += " {} ".format(ch)
        out.extend(temp.split())
```

You could also use a set of punctuation chars and change the logic checking if a char appears in the set or not:

```
st = set("""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~""")
with open("text.txt") as f:
    out = []
    for line in f:
        temp = ""
        for ch in line:
            if ch not in st:
                temp += ch
            else:
                temp += " {} ".format(ch)
        out.extend(temp.split())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It now works! But my python is giving up whenever I try this program on a text file that has a lot of characters. Like a book for example. Is there any way to for something like this to be more optimized?

Comment: I will add on alternative when i get back on my comp.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the lines to a list of individual characters ( `l` ).

Then check if a character is an alphanumeric or not, while the current char is an alphanumeric ( `isalnum()` ), it is combined to a string ( `comb` ), this string is added to the output list ( `out` ) when a non-alphanumeric is found, then adds the non-alphanumerics separately until an alphanumeric is found again.

`out` is then filtered from newlines and spaces.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    l = f.readlines()

    # separates each character into a list
    l = list(l)

    # output list
    out = []

    # string in which alphanumerics will be combined
    comb = ''

    # loops through chars
    # comb is added with chars while char is alphanumberic,
    # comb is added to out when a non-alphanumeric char is detected 
    # and then it resets, and the char detected as punc is added as well
    for ch in l:
        if ch.isalnum():
            comb += ch
        else:
            out.append(comb)
            out.append(ch)
            comb = ''

    # filters out from space and newlines
    out = [ s for s in out if s != '' and s != '\n' and s != ' ' ]

    print(out)
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'boy', "'", 'cat', "'", 'dog', ',', 'egg', 'fin', 'goat', 'hat', 'ice', '!']
```